# How to detect if the first number of my input is a specific number?

Tags: jquery

I need to verify if the first number of the input is 5 or 4.

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="first_six_digits" name="first_six_digits">
```

I've tried this:

```
$('#first_six_digits').on('keypress', function (e){
    var first = this.value.charAt(0),
        master = false,
        visa = false;

    switch(first){
        case e.keyCode == 53:
            master = true;
            alert('master');
            break;

        case e.keyCode == 52:
            visa = true;
            alert('visa');
            break;
    };
});
```

I don't know how to compare the first number `var first = this.value.charAt(0)` to `e.keyCode == 53`.

Comment: `first == '5' || first == '4'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how to write a switch. Your condition must be inside the switch() part, and each case should be a constant value to compare against the condition, not a comparison.

Also, charAt() returns a character, not a keyCode.

```
    switch(first){
        case '5':
            master = true;
            alert('master');
            break;

        case '4':
            visa = true;
            alert('visa');
            break;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
case e.keyCode == 53:
```

use

```
case '5':
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you just check like this ?

```
$('#first_six_digits').on('keyup', function (e){
    var first = this.value.charAt(0),
        master = false,
        visa = false;
    //check what is the first value
    switch(first){
        case '6':
            master = true;
            alert('master');
            break;

        case '5':
            visa = true;
            alert('visa');
            break;
    };
});
```

[Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xsp4v579/)